# Pdo экранирование кавычек

Tags: php, pdo, экранирование

Нужно в базу добавлять текст с кавычками (<kbd>'</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>), предварительно экранируя их.
Через `mysqli_real_escape_string` - в базу добавляет значения, вместе с кавычками.

А через `pdo->prepare()` и `pdo->quote()` - нет.

так не работает, если в тексте будут кавычки:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO news(text) VALUES('$noFilter')";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
```

так тоже, если будут кавычки в тексте:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO news(text) VALUES('$noFilter')";
    $query = $pdo->quote($sql);
```

Как быть?

Comment: Необходимо больше конкретики. Покажите как именно добавляете данные в базу.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO `news`(text) VALUES('$noFilter')";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

Answer (score 5):

Не подставлять значения напрямую, а использовать плейсхолдеры

```
 $query = 'INSERT INTO news (text) VALUES (:text)';
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $statement->bindValue(':text', $text);
 $statement->execute();
```

Comment: И правда, через плейсхолдер работает. Правда я в array() добавил execute()